# Uniform line height with tabularx-- possibly due to mix of Russian and English?

Tags: tables, tabularx, babel, input-encodings, russian

I have a table using `tabularx`:

[image: table using tabularx]

As you see, the line heights are not uniform. I would like every line to be the same height as the third row (inanimate | no change).

I tried `[1ex]`, and there is no change, even with, for example, `[0.1ex]`
Any advice is appreciated. Here is my preamble and code for the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

\title{Lorem}
\author{Ipsum}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth} { 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | }
 \hline
 Ending / Description& How to Decline \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Masculine} \\
 \hline
inanimate  & no change  \\
 \hline
 animate, a consonant  & \selectlanguage{russian}+а\selectlanguage{english} \\
 \hline
 animate, \selectlanguage{russian}й\selectlanguage{english}  & \selectlanguage{russian}-й, +я\selectlanguage{english}  \\
 \hline
 animate, \selectlanguage{russian}ь\selectlanguage{english}  & \selectlanguage{russian}-ь, +я\selectlanguage{english}  \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Feminine} \\
 \hline
 \selectlanguage{russian}а\selectlanguage{english}  & \selectlanguage{russian}-а, +у\selectlanguage{english} \\
 \hline
 \selectlanguage{russian}я\selectlanguage{english}  & \selectlanguage{russian}-я, +ю\selectlanguage{english}  \\
 \hline
 \selectlanguage{russian}ь\selectlanguage{english}  & no change   \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Neuter} \\
 \hline
 all nouns  & no change \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Always make a complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer isn't that what I've done? I've copied the entire table -- thought that would be it.

Comment: @Joseph no, you should add the relevant packages you use, the class, etc... Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ah, thank you @Rmano. I'm new to LaTeX. I will add the preamble to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regular `tabular`  and the `w` column type from the `array` package you can get the following output. I also slightly shortened the code by using `\foreignlanguage{russian}{...}` instead of `\selectlanguage{russian}...\selectlanguage{english}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

\title{Lorem}
\author{Ipsum}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ 
  | wc{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
  | >{\selectlanguage{russian}} wc{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}<{\selectlanguage{english}} | }
 \hline
 Ending / Description                   & \selectlanguage{english}How to Decline \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Masculine} \\
 \hline
 inanimate                              & \selectlanguage{english}no change  \\
 \hline
 animate, a consonant                   & +а \\
 \hline
 animate, \foreignlanguage{russian}{й}  & -й, +я \\
 \hline
 animate, \foreignlanguage{russian}{ь}  & -ь, +я  \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Feminine} \\
 \hline
 \foreignlanguage{russian}{а}           & -а, +у \\
 \hline
 \foreignlanguage{russian}{я}           & -я, +ю  \\
 \hline
 \foreignlanguage{russian}{ь}           & \selectlanguage{english} no change   \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Neuter} \\
 \hline
 all nouns  & no change \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I you can switch to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you could load the `fontspec` package and dispense with all `\foreignlanguage` and `\selectlanguage` directives in the table.

[image]

```
%% to compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{New Computer Modern}

%%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx} % 'tabularx' loads 'array' automatically
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}


%%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1} % '1' is the default


\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slightly more open "look"
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth} { | C | C | }
 \hline
 Ending / Description & How to Decline \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Masculine} \\
 \hline
inanimate  & no change  \\
 \hline
 animate, a consonant  & +а \\
 \hline
 animate, й  & -й, +я  \\
 \hline
 animate, ь  & -ь, +я  \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Feminine} \\
 \hline
 а  & -а, +у \\
 \hline
 я  & -я, +ю  \\
 \hline
 ь  & no change   \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Neuter} \\
 \hline
 all nouns  & no change \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's great, it's been so annoying having to switch languages all the time!

Comment: @Joseph Note that it’s also possible to switch languages automatically, which gets you the correct hyphenation patterns, and possibly a different font. You might wish to do this if you need more than isolated words in Russian.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the presence of `\selectlanguage{russian}`, because this command should always go *between* paragraphs and the start of an `X` column is not the right place. Replace with `\foreignlanguage` as shown below.

It's quite rare to use explicit `\selectlanguage`: I can imagine it only in documents sections in different languages. The environments `otherlanguage` and `otherlanguage*` are more useful, together with `\foreignlanguage` for a short insert of text.

By the way, table cells form group, so there's no need to use `\selectlanguage{english}`.

Note that the last declared encoding is the default one, so if the default language is English then T1 should come last.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}

\title{Lorem}
\author{Ipsum}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth} { 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
  | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | }
 \hline
 Ending / Description& How to Decline \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Masculine} \\
 \hline
inanimate  & no change  \\
 \hline
 animate, a consonant  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{+а} \\
 \hline
 animate, \foreignlanguage{russian}{й}  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{-й, +я}  \\
 \hline
 animate, \foreignlanguage{russian}{ь}  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{-ь, +я}  \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Feminine} \\
 \hline
 \foreignlanguage{russian}{а}  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{-а, +у} \\
 \hline
 \foreignlanguage{russian}{я}  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{-я, +ю}  \\
 \hline
 \foreignlanguage{russian}{ь}  & no change   \\
 \hline
 \rowcolor{light-gray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Neuter} \\
 \hline
 all nouns  & no change \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might consider a different layout for your table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ @{\qquad} l c @{} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Ending/Description} & How to Decline \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Masculine} \\
inanimate  & no change  \\
 animate, a consonant  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{+а} \\
 animate, \foreignlanguage{russian}{й}  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{-й, +я}  \\
 animate, \foreignlanguage{russian}{ь}  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{-ь, +я}  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Feminine} \\
\foreignlanguage{russian}{а}  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{-а, +у} \\
\foreignlanguage{russian}{я}  & \foreignlanguage{russian}{-я, +ю}  \\
\foreignlanguage{russian}{ь}  & no change   \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\itshape Neuter} \\
 all nouns  & no change \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help